# Magento 2: Google search console giving error: Error on Either "offers", "review", or "aggregateRating" should be specified

Tags: magento2, seo, google-analytics, ratings, product-review

We are getting an error on google search console for multiple products: Either "offers", "review", or "aggregateRating" should be specified

Comment: what's the question? What are those and how to solve them?

Comment: Google is complaining because you pages have incomplete product schema (https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product)

Comment: @jiheison How to fix it?

Comment: Fixing depends on your use-case and how much effort you want to expend. There seem to be "rich snippet" extensions available and tutorials on how to implement the changes yourself if you search for "magento schema.org". The root of Google's problem is that the product schema is only partially implemented on your pages. If you don't care about the benefits of schema.org, you have the option of removing the parts that are already included from your templates.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into you suggestion.